# Rails comments and username won't show up in post views / undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a post.rb model where I can display who wrote the post in the show post view, and that works wonderfully.

However, I've been trying to add comments, which belong to a post, and also belong to a user.

**I can't seem to get all the comments or the names of the users who posted the coments to show up in the post show.html.erb.**

I guess my question is, how do I integrate controller and model information in between controller and model views? I know if it exists in the model and controller and view of the same type, it is accessible, but cross-linking or sharing controller model information is hard for me.

I want to be able to display the user that made the comment, along with the body of the comment in the show view of the post, and not the comment.

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates :body, :presence => true
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates :user, presence: true;

  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5}


  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  validates :title, :slug, presence: true

  # comments
  has_many :comments

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :school_name, presence: true, inclusion: { in: %w(Harvard Yale),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid choice" }

  validates :graduation_year, presence: true, inclusion: { in: %w(2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid choice currently" }

    def superadmin?
      self.role.name == "Superadmin"
    end 

end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
# GET /posts/:post_id/comments
# GET /posts/:post_id/comments.xml

def index
#1st you retrieve the post thanks to params[:post_id]
post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
#2nd you get all the comments of this post
@comments = post.comments

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @comments }
end
 end

 # GET /posts/:post_id/comments/:id
 # GET /comments/:id.xml
 def show
 #1st you retrieve the post thanks to params[:post_id]
 post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
 #2nd you retrieve the comment thanks to params[:id]
 @comment = post.comments.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
end
end

# GET /posts/:post_id/comments/new
# GET /posts/:post_id/comments/new.xml
def new
#1st you retrieve the post thanks to params[:post_id]
post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
#2nd you build a new one
@comment = post.comments.new(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user

end

# GET /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit
def edit
#1st you retrieve the post thanks to params[:post_id]
post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
#2nd you retrieve the comment thanks to params[:id]
@comment = post.comments.find(comment_params[:id])
end

# POST /posts/:post_id/comments
# POST /posts/:post_id/comments.xml
def create
#1st you retrieve the post thanks to params[:post_id]
post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
#2nd you create the comment with arguments in params[:comment]
@comment = post.comments.create(comment_params)
@comment.user = current_user


respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    #1st argument of redirect_to is an array, in order to build the correct route to the nested resource comment
    format.html { redirect_to([@comment.post, @comment], :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
    #the key :location is associated to an array in order to build the correct route to the nested resource comment
    format.xml  { render :xml => @comment, :status => :created, :location => [@comment.post, @comment] }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `show` method of your `post_controller`, you'll need to do something like:

```
def show 
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id]) # or however you find your post
  ....
end
```

Then, in your `views/posts/_show.html.erb` (if you're using erb), you'll do something like:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  ... show some comment stuff 
  <%= comment.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How come when I try to input the form it gives me this error?

undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass

`<%= form_for([@comment.post, @comment]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
 
<p class="the-post-text">
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>
<% end %>`

Comment: Because you haven't set the `@comment` variable. Which controller/action does that view belong to?

Comment: @comment has CommentsController.rb, comment.rb, and views as /comments with new.html.erb show.html.erb and index.html.erb and _form.html.erb

Comment: That sounds like a new question. If your original question was answered, you should accept it and then post a new question. It's not really feasible to answer questions in the comment section. Feel free to tag me if you post a new question.